# How does RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version'] get set?

Tags: ruby

I noticed that although my `Gemfile` specifies Ruby 2.6.3 and `ruby -v` returns 2.6.3, I have a directory inside `vendor/bundle/ruby` called `2.6.0` and not one called `2.6.3`.

I also noticed that if I run `RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']` inside an IRB console, I get `"2.6.0"`, not 2.6.3.

Why is `RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']` set to 2.6.0 instead of 2.6.3? What controls it?

Comment: None. This is on a production machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Mac, you can find rbconfig file in `/Users/<username>/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18` or somewhere alike.

Inside it, the comment says:

```
# The module storing Ruby interpreter configurations on building.
#
# This file was created by mkconfig.rb when ruby was built.  It contains
# build information for ruby which is used e.g. by mkmf to build
# compatible native extensions.  Any changes made to this file will be
# lost the next time ruby is built.
```

It turned out this file is generated by `tool/mkconfig.rb` script during the build process. Let's check it out.

```rb
versions = {}
IO.foreach(File.join(srcdir, "version.h")) do |l|
  m = /^\s*#\s*define\s+RUBY_(PATCHLEVEL)\s+(-?\d+)/.match(l)
  if m
    versions[m[1]] = m[2]
    break if versions.size == 4
    next
  end
  m = /^\s*#\s*define\s+RUBY_VERSION_(\w+)\s+(-?\d+)/.match(l)
  if m
    versions[m[1]] = m[2]
    break if versions.size == 4
    next
  end
  m = /^\s*#\s*define\s+RUBY_VERSION\s+\W?([.\d]+)/.match(l)
  if m
    versions['MAJOR'], versions['MINOR'], versions['TEENY'] = m[1].split('.')
    break if versions.size == 4
    next
  end
end
if versions.size != 4
  IO.foreach(File.join(srcdir, "include/ruby/version.h")) do |l|
    m = /^\s*#\s*define\s+RUBY_API_VERSION_(\w+)\s+(-?\d+)/.match(l)
    if m
      versions[m[1]] ||= m[2]
      break if versions.size == 4
      next
    end
  end
end
%w[MAJOR MINOR TEENY PATCHLEVEL].each do |v|
  print "  CONFIG[#{v.dump}] = #{(versions[v]||vars[v]).dump}\n"
end
```

And this is the logic to generate `RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']`.

Two files referenced in the file are `version.h` and `include/ruby/version.h`, which you might find interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't seem to have a `~/.rubies` directory on my Mac. Also, the machine I'm mainly concerned with is running Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: You can find `rbconfig.rb` the way you like, such as using `find` or `fd` command.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was able to find the file using `locate rbconfig.rb`.